# Updating prices for products using a .csv programmatically

Tags: soap, programmatically, product-prices, database-update

My question more broad at the beginning but I will go more into detail later. 
I have around 3000 products where I have the Skus and prices in a .csv file. Now the prices changed recently and I would like to upload/update these prices of the products.
Is there a quick way to do this via a script using the SOAP API?

Or is there an easier way around this?

**UPDATE**
I have used this function http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-prices-in-magento-in-easier-faster-way/ but now the value and price mismatch. Are there any better options going through a csv and then match the prices for each sku to a price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that using the SOAP services will get you what you need fast. I mean it will probably work, but it will be really slow for 3k products.
Instead try this script.
Let's say that your csv has 2 columns. SKU and price.

```
$skuIndex = 0;
$priceIndex = 1;
$csv = 'path/to/file.csv';
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
//an array to keep the products by price
$productIdsByPrice = array();
//a product model instance
$productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
//read the csv
$io->streamOpen($csv, 'r+');
while($csvData = $io->streamReadCsv()){
   if (count($csvData) < 2) { //skip rows with less than 2 columns
       continue;
   }
   $sku = trim($csvData[$skuIndex]);
   //get the product id by sku
   $id = $productModel->getIdBySku($sku);
   if ($id) {
      //if the id exists then mark it for update
      $price = trim($csvData[$priceIndex]);
      if (!isset($productIdsByPrice[$price])) {
         $productIdsByPrice[$price] = array();
      }
      $productIdsByPrice[$price][] = $id;
   }
}
//now you should have the product ids you need to update grouped by price
//just do the fast update
foreach ($productIdsByPrice as $price => $ids) {
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
        $ids, //what products to update
        array('price' => $price), //what attributes to update
        0 //store id for update
    )
}
```

you can place this code in one of your custom models or helpers and then run it. You may want to double check the code. I haven't tested it. Also backup your db.

**[EDIT]**

If you run this from a file, create one called `price_update.php` on the same level as `index.php` and add this in it:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd()); 
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php'; 
require_once $mageFilename; 
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

After this, add the code from above that parses the csv and call in your browser `MAGE_ROOT/price_update.php`.

Comment: Ok that looks great. Would it be possible to call that from a php file or not?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: I get a Internal Server Error 500. I´m trying to figure out why

Comment: Hey Marius, do you have any idea why I would get that Internal Server Error 500 when i try to use the Php file?

Comment: I don't know. Like I said I haven't tested the code. Try doing a step by step debug and see the line that fails.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Just created availability, price, cost CSV-updater.
Interested in development or contribution, so posting it here.

http://lycenok.com/magento-extensions/magento-csv-product-updater.html
https://github.com/lycenok/magento_csv_product_updater

Regards, Eugene.

**UPDATE:** Remember about the simple solution, implemented in Magento itself.

System -> Import/Export -> "Dataflow - profiles"