# Mass updates of prices using a .csv file

Tags: price, product-attribute, database-update

I am updating around 2500 product prices and I thought I can simply use the import/export function from Magento.

What I´ve done is an export of all products, updated the .csv file and now I want to import all the products again, in small batches of 200-300 products.
For the export I only used the "SKU" and "price" and thats all what I want to import again also.

I´ve used my dev instance to do a test and it worked fine for all 2500 products, besides the fact that it took really long.

Now before I want to use it on my live instance I was wondering if there is anything missing or if anything could go wrong the way i do it.
I´m thinking about Flat Catalog data or will this be ok?

Comment: Are you exporting all attributes or only price attribute?

Comment: I´ve updated my question, but I only use SKU and price

Comment: Indexes should be invalid after importing. Be ready to run the re-indexing as soon as you finish importing.

Comment: What effects will that have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded the .csv file and after that re-indexed all Indexes and then it was working as expected and the prices were updated so all good.
So I recommend

1) Make sure your .csv file is consistent

2) Make a test run on your development site with re-indexing after the upload

3) Do the same steps on the live system, shouldn´t take too long for a few products, and I have split up my 3000 products in 3 parts so 1k products each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some solutions from answers here.
[Updating prices for products using a .csv programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58837/updating-prices-for-products-using-a-csv-programmatically/199155#199155)

1. http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-prices-in-magento-in-easier-faster-way/
2. https://github.com/lycenok/magento_csv_product_updater